# How to protect Excel cell contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml

How can I protect Excel cells contents in a worksheet and also in its xml file format?
I want the cells to be read-only.

Answer (score 1):

You should make the file read-only.  Find the file in explorer, right click, then select "Read-Only", then select OK.

There is no way to do it on individual cells of an XML file, you can only do it to the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible for the XML file format.
Binary Excel files can be protected usign the regular means (workbook/worksheet protection, or file protection, or both).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make cells in a excel sheet read-only, you can do:

- Populate the cell
- Choose `Data -> Validation`
- Use `Custom` for `Allow`
- Use the formula `=""`

Comment: This won't do anything different from what normal sheet protection already does. It does add unnecessary complexity and size to the file itself. Best just to make the cells protected (in the format cells > protection dialog) then password protect the sheet and workbook. It's not perfect, but it will help.